# Как удалить (вычесть) из одного диапазона дат другогой диапазон дат?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть две таблицы с двумя диапазонами дат, которые пересекаются:

```
create table t1 (df,dl) as  
    select date'2020-01-01' df, date'2020-06-24' dl from dual

create table t2 (df,dl) as  
    select date'2020-05-01' df, date'2020-05-31' dl from dual
```

Как удалить (вычесть) из диапазона дат одного диапазона дат, диапазон другого, то есть, где пересекается?

Ожидаемый результат:

```
  df         | dl
  -----------------------
  01.01.2020 | 30.04.2020
  01.06.2020 | 24.04.2020
```

Или визуально так:

```
[-------------------------]
          [------]
             =
[--------]        
                  [-------]
```

или так:

```
[-------------------------]
          [-------------------]
             =
[--------]
```

Comment: Добрый день. появилось ли усовершенствование данного запроса у автора? чтобы можно было получить оставшиеся интервалы, когда конец первого отрезка заканчивается раньше чем конец второго отрезка. И если есть подскажите как запросом получить  "пустоты", т.е. когда они не пересекаются, но надо получить "пропуск" между интервалами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простого и удобного способа вычитать диапазоны дат в Oracle я не нашел, поэтому попробовал написать запрос вручную.

«Остатки» от вычитания получаются в двух случаях:

1. Если начало первого отрезка раньше начала второго.
2. Если конец первого отрезка позже конца второго.

Построим запросы для каждого случая в отдельности и сольем результаты:

```
select t1.df, least(t1.dl, t2.df - 1) as dl
  from t1
  join t2
    on t1.df < t2.df
union all
select greatest(t2.dl + 1, t1.df) as df, t1.dl
  from t1
  join t2
    on t1.dl > t2.dl
```

Стоит иметь ввиду, что если второй отрезок полностью перекрывает первый, то разница совсем не попадет в результат. К тому же запрос предполагает что все отрезки «невырожденные» и `df` всегда раньше `dl`.

Проверим на нескольких примерах:

```
create table t1 (id,df,dl) as  
    select 1 as id,  date'2020-01-01' df, date'2020-06-24' dl from dual
    union all
    select 2 as id,  date'2020-02-01' df, date'2020-05-15' dl from dual
    union all
    select 3 as id,  date'2020-05-10' df, date'2020-07-01' dl from dual
    union all
    select 4 as id,  date'2020-05-01' df, date'2020-05-31' dl from dual;
    

create table t2 (df,dl) as  
    select date'2020-05-01' df, date'2020-05-31' dl from dual;  

select *
  from (select t1.id, t1.df, least(t1.dl, t2.df - 1) as dl
          from t1
          join t2
            on t1.df < t2.df
        union all
        select t1.id, greatest(t2.dl + 1, t1.df) as df, t1.dl
          from t1
          join t2
            on t1.dl > t2.dl)
 order by id, df, dl
```

Получаем результаты:

| ID | DF | DL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2020 | 30.04.2020 |
| 1 | 01.06.2020 | 24.06.2020 |
| 2 | 01.02.2020 | 30.04.2020 |
| 3 | 01.06.2020 | 01.07.2020 |